# How to convert specific text into hyperlink?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to find specific text in a string, and if found wrap it in a link.

[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/sol_b/pen/QdOWVp)

The text I am looking for is in the format:

**number | letter | 4 random numbers**

Example: **7Q3847**

With jQuery I can find *one* example (where the random numbers are hard-coded) and successfully convert it into a link. Here is my code so far:

```
$('.text').each(function(){
    var code = '7Q2992';
    code = code.replace(/\W/g, '');
    var str = code.split(" ");
    var link = $(this).text();
    text = link.replace(str, "<a href='https://www.google.ie/?gws_rd=cr&ei=4j6LWLm4DcbYU6-KvZgB#safe=active&q=" + code + "'>" + str + "</a>");
    $(this).html(text);
});
```

What I'd like instead, is to have the var `code` be able to search for any text starting with the 7Q or 7T...

I would appreciate any help with this!

**FULL SNIPPET**

```js
$('.text').each(function() {
  var code = '7Q2992';
  code = code.replace(/\W/g, '');
  var str = code.split(" ");
  var link = $(this).text();
  text = link.replace(str, "<a href='https://www.google.ie/?gws_rd=cr&ei=4j6LWLm4DcbYU6-KvZgB#safe=active&q=" + code + "'>" + str + "</a>");
  $(this).html(text);
});
```

```css
body {
  width: 580px;
  margin: 50px auto 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.output {
  float: left;
}
.ideal {
  float: right;
}
header {
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}
.red {
  background: red;
}
.green {
  background: green;
}
p {
  line-height: 1.5;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="output">
  <header class="red">Current output</header>
  <p class="text">
    Text containing letters 7Q2992
  </p>
  <p class="text">
    Text containing letters 7T3940
  </p>
  <p class="text">
    Text containing letters 7Q3940
  </p>
</div>
<div class="ideal">
  <header class="green">Desired output</header>
  <p>
    Text containing letters
    <a href="https://www.google.ie/?gws_rd=cr&ei=4j6LWLm4DcbYU6-KvZgB#safe=active&q=7Q2992">7Q2992</a> 
  </p>
  <p>
    Text containing letters <a href="https://www.google.ie/?gws_rd=cr&ei=4j6LWLm4DcbYU6-KvZgB#safe=active&q=7T3940">7T3940</a>
  </p>
  <p>
    Text containing letters <a href="https://www.google.ie/?gws_rd=cr&ei=4j6LWLm4DcbYU6-KvZgB#safe=active&q=7Q3940">7Q3940</a>
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$1` to place matched element back to text.

So replacement would be `/(\d\w\d{4})/` to `<a href="$1">$1</a>`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.output .text, .ideal p').each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text().replace(/(\d\w\d{4})/i, '<a href="http://google.com/$1">#$1</a>');

    $(this).html(text);
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="output">
  <header class="red">Current output</header>
  <p class="text">
    Text containing letters 7Q2992
  </p>
  <p class="text">
    Text containing letters 7T3940
  </p>
  <p class="text">
    Text containing letters 7Q3940
  </p>
</div>
<div class="ideal">
  <header class="green">Desired output</header>
  <p>
    Text containing letters 7Q2992
  </p>
  <p>
    Text containing letters 7T3940
  </p>
  <p>
    Text containing letters 7Q3940
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: This works very well, and I like the simplicity for updating the URL. Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Instead of manually using value use regex string:

```
\d{1}[a-zA-Z]{1}\d{4}\g
```

This regex matches string with 1 digit,1 alphabet char, 4 digits.

Comment: If using `\d` so why not use `\w`? :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try following regex to do this

```
var text = "hello test 7Q2992";
text = text.replace(/(7Q.*)\b/g, "<a href='https://www.google.ie/?gws_rd=cr&ei=4j6LWLm4DcbYU6-KvZgB#safe=active&q=$1'>$1</a>");
console.log(text)
```

Above regex will find any string which start with `7Q` and will wrap that into anchor tag. Let me know if you want this expression to be more specific such as.. It should check for 4 digits after 7Q. We can add that as well

In case you want to add constrain for 4 numbers  ... try following

```
var text = "hello test 7Q2992";
text = text.replace(/(7Q[0-9]{4})\b/g, "<a href='https://www.google.ie/?gws_rd=cr&ei=4j6LWLm4DcbYU6-KvZgB#safe=active&q=$1'>$1</a>");
console.log(text)
```

Comment: Sorry, but explain pattern `7q().*`. Why `()`? Why hard-coded `7Q`? Why `.*`? It will match `7qahsdkjahsdkjhaksdjhkasjhdkajshfksjdhg`

Comment: @Justinas sorry for the typo in expression. I mentioned to poster if he needs a specific condition and have also provided another expression